# Where to get com.android.calendar for Android 4.0.3 from?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, installation, calendar, apk

I accidentally deleted the package com.android.calendar.

Now it refuses to sync my Google Calendar.

Where can I get this specific package to install it back to /system using Link2SD?

**Model specifications:**

```
HUAWEI U8666E
4.0.3
Baseband version: 2030
Kernel version: 3.0.8-perf-00271-g4fdddbe
Build number: U8666E-1V100R001C40B935
```

Comment: Tell us the exact model - maybe someone could grab a factory image and extract it for you. Ones from other models might not be an exact fit.

Comment: @AndyYan please see my update.

Comment: Standby, downloading from external site - will share after it finishes. I will also refer you to the original link in case you need other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Russians over at 4PDA have a [thread](http://4pda.ru/forum/lofiversion/index.php?t440972.html) dedicated to the phone, which hosts a number of firmwares, including stock-based ones. Here is the Calendar app extracted from the "Stock+" one, uploaded to my [AndroidFileHost](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=673368273298925596) for your convenience. You can also get other files from the package in case you need them.

As validation, the version number of the ROM as extracted from `build.prop`:

> ro.build.version.incremental=C40B935
>
> ro.build.tags=release-keys
>
> ro.build.description=U8666E-user 4.0.3 GRJ90 C40B935 release-keys
>
> ro.build.fingerprint=Huawei/U8666E/hwu8666e:4.0.3/HuaweiU8666E/C40B935:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys
>
> ro.confg.hw_appsbootversion=U8666E-1V100R001C40B935_APPSBOOT
>
> ro.confg.hw_appversion=U8666E-1V100R001C40B935_KERNEL
>
> ro.confg.hw_appfsversion=U8666E-1V100R001C40B935_SYSIMG

"B935" - matches your current ROM exactly.